# Converting 2D XNA 4.0 project to silverlight 5.0

Tags: silverlight, xna, xna-4.0

I followed the tutorial on http://silversprite.codeplex.com/ and got rid of a few issues that were expected (the colors etc). But there is 1 compile error left:

Error   2   The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll' and 'C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\SilverSprite.dll'    C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Projects\Other projects\Game Jam prac\Silverlight3dApp1\Silverlight3dApp1\Silverlight3dApp\VertexPositionColorNormal.cs    31

I've been searching for over an hour and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says: There is a type, `VertexDeclaration`, that is being defined by both Silver**light** and by Silver**Sprite**. When your project tries to resolve which one to use - it can't decide.

SilverSprite is, and has always been, kind of buggy. This appears to be a bug in SilverSprite. It's coming from [this file](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74170#1685200), which contains a declaration of `VertexDeclaration` which is [nothing like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexdeclaration_members) the actual API.

Fortunately you don't have to implement it yourself - because Silverlight provides it. I suggest you download the SilverSprite source and include it as a project in your solution, and reference that instead of the DLL (ie: build SilverSprite from source yourself). Then you can easily modify it and simply delete the bogus type definition - your code will then automatically use the real one.

If you come across any other bugs, I suggest you look at [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/). I made it last time I tried to use SilverSprite (although this was before Silverlight 5) - and I fixed many, many bugs. You might find it useful to salvage code from.